# Refresh pageblocksection

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a pageblock section .. and a button Clear Details 
This button should refresh the pageblocksection and show blank values

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="Test">
    <apex:inputField value="{!Test1.Title__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!Test1.Name__c}" />
</apex:pageblocksection>
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="Clear" action="{!clearDetails}" rerender="Test"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save Details" Action="{!save}" />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Apex Code:-

```
 public PageReference clearDetails()
 {
        PageReference pageRef = null;
        return pageRef;
 }
```

Comment: You appear to be on the good way, what is it you're having trouble with ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-initialize the `Test1` object as well:

```
public PageReference clearDetails()
{
    Test1 = new Test1();    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: good catch didnt notice that.  I didnt use the provided apex when i tested

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the fields in an outputPanel and refresh that panel as well

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="Test">

    <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Test1.Title__c}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Test1.Name__c}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:pageblocksection>
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="Clear" action="{!clearDetails}" rerender="Test,panel"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save Details" Action="{!save}" />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```